# Расширение Google Chrome событие загрузки страницы на вкладке

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chrome-extension

(Сделал, как ответили в комментариях, но еще одна проблема осталась)

Учусь делать расширения для Chrome

Необходимо среагировать на загрузку страницы во вкладке

В манифесте добавил разрешения

```
"permissions": [
        "activeTab", "tabs", "webRequest"
    ]
```

А так же background

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
```

в backround.js - пытаюсь отловить chrome.tabs.onUpdated:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(id, info, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"alert('"+tab.url+"');"});
});
```

Но alert отрабатывает **только когда открыт *popup***

В чем проблема?

Comment: `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` нужно писать в `background.js`, а не в `popup.js`

Comment: не надо js вообще вставлять в какой либо html. js описывается прямо в манифесте. html вы делаете только в случае если вам надо показать пользователю какие нибудь всплывающие сообщения по нажатию на кнопку вашего расширения рядом с адресной строкой

Comment: В итоге пришел пока что к этому https://javascript.ru/forum/css-html/72687-rasshirenie-google-chrome-sobytie-zagruzki-stranicy-na-vkladke.html#post478507

Comment: Проблема понял в чем - если скрипты с загружаемой вкладки все сбрасываются
Так что просто можно сказать алерт, без привязки ко вкладке